# How to prove a sum formula about powers of 2 and 3?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, exact-sequence

I discovered this yesterday and I am wondering:

1. Is this a well known formula?
2. How do I go about proving something like this? (Beyond induction.)

$$2^{2n} = 3^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}3^{n-k-1}2^{2k}$$

Thank you. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

P.s: For notation purposes, when $n=0$ the sum is not evaluated.

Comment: Use the geometric sum formula $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = (1-x^n) / (1-x)$

Comment: @JairTaylor: it is unclear to me, how that helps.

Comment: Close, but it does not explain the powers of 2. And after you add in the binomial coeficients, it explains things even less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is:
$$3^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}3^{n-k-1}2^{2k}=3^n+3^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac43\right)^{k}=3^n+3^{n-1}\frac{\left(\frac43\right)^n-1}{\frac43-1}=\\
3^n+(4^n-3^n)=4^n=2^{2n}.$$

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. Also, I have to wait 4 minutes to accept an answer, -_-.

Comment: No hurry, you should wait longer to see if others can provide more elegant solutions. Good luck.